# After update Mac OSX Sierra, iPhone can not connect to Mac's localhost

Tags: iphone, macos

Last night I updated my Mac to the already-vilified OSX Sierra 10.12.4.

Tonight, I went to test my localhost webapp on iPhone. Prior to tonight, this worked by browsing in iPhone Safari to address 192.168.1.64:1337. My IP has not changed.

Tonight, iPhone Safari returns, "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server."

How to re-connect iPhone???

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. I was using MAMP PRO and in the end i switched to use the "via Xip.io (LAN only)" option under Hosts/General/Name resolution. I also had to update my database to reflect the url it provided and clear the site cache. All works perfectly again using this different method.

Comment: You could have used the comments to post this. Post an answer ONLY if you're trying to post a solution to the OP's problem.